# When I am executing a 'select' query on two tables it renders all the elements inside the table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, reference, foreign-keys

I created a table called 'parent'

```
Create table parent (p_id int(11) primary key, p_name varchar(255));
```

And another table called "child" with foreign key referenced to the parent Id table as below

```
Create table child (ch_id int(11), primary key, ch_name varchar(255), ch_fk int(11) references parent(p_id));
```

Both tables were created successfully and I add some data in both of them. But when I tried to get the data of a parent and his children it renders all available data of the child table
My query is as below.

```
 Select * from parent , child where p_id=2
```

[image: 'ch_fk' is the foreign key]

Comment: Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax with an `ON` clause.

Comment: Can u fix my query please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to join the tables explicitly - otherwise you end up with a [cartesian product](https://www.mathstopia.net/sets/cartesian-product), where all rows on one side are joined to all rows on the other side.

I suspect what you want is:

```
 SELECT * FROM parent p INNER JOIN child c ON p.p_id = c_ch_fk WHERE p_id=2
```